# Multiple backup images on windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, backup

I'm making backup images of my windows 10 (version 1607) system via "*Control Panel \ File History \ System Image Backup*"

I save the image to an external hd but the images are overwritten in the WindowsImageBackup folder.

Is there a way to save different images, let's say i want an image "fresh install", an image "fresh install with tools" and an image "fresh install with dev tools"?

So if an installation isn't right for me, or my system gets messed up, i can restore a previous image?

thanks in advance

Comment: This isn't really a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  You need to rename the folder under *WindowsImageBackup*, wich is your pc name.
When restoring an image you'll get a list of all different images.